# Hide all the elements with a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and really enjoying it but I am now facing a problem which is a bit confusing to me.

I wrote the code below to hide all the element with a class `male`, but It does not work. When I replace the class `male` by an `id` the code start working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-register" method="post" action="">

            <div class="form-title-row">
                <h1>Create an account</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Gender</span>
                    <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                        <option value="none">Select One</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row" class="male">
                <label>
                    <span>First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row" class="male">
                <label>
                    <span>Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Email</span>
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".male").hide();
            $("#dropdown").change(function(){
                if ($("#dropdown").val() == "male") {
                    $(".male").show();
                } else {
                    $(".male").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

I do not really know how to solve this problem. Kindly help me.

Comment: [___`must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to`___](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have double `class` attribute for elements meaning only first `class` will take effect and leading to no elements with class `.male`

You can list multiple classes using space inside same `class` attribute:

```
<div class="form-row male">
```

---

*Optimized JS code*

You can use `.toggle(true/false)` to tell if element must be hidden or shown.

Also I suggest add css for `.male`: `.male {display: none;}` to prevent element from being displayed while JS is still processed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".male").hide();

    $("#dropdown").change(function(){
        $(".male").toggle($("#dropdown").val() == "male");
    });
});
```

Comment: More simplified code would be `$(this).val()` or even better would be `this.value`

Answer (score 7):

You can't have two `class` attributes in your html, the way to set up more than one `class` is on the same attribute with a space between each `class`.

Change your code like this:

```
class="form-row male"
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try changing to this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-register" method="post" action="">

            <div class="form-title-row">
                <h1>Create an account</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Gender</span>
                    <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                        <option value="none">Select One</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row male">
                <label>
                    <span>First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row male">
                <label>
                    <span>Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Email</span>
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".male").hide();
            $("#dropdown").change(function(){
                if ($("#dropdown").val() == "male") {
                    $(".male").show();
                } else {
                    $(".male").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

What I did was changing this:
`<div class="form-row" class="male">`
to this
`<div class="form-row male">`

Answer (score 1):

> class="form-row" class="male"

should be replaced with

> class="form-row male"

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have same attribute that is `class` declared multiple time on same element.

Declaring same attribute multiple times for a single element (Invalid HTML),will let the first value to override all subsequent values for the same attribute.

So in this case, your element need to have only one `class` attribute

This behavior is explained here [**Attribute-name-state**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attribute-name-state)

`<div class="form-row male">`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1u02hf/1/)